# how to set default date in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, datetime

i want to configure jQuery UI that they never set date who already gone. means only futurewise date allowed or the value i want to set is now. means current [today]'s date.

`$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate : new Date(Date.now()),
        defaultDate: new Date(Date.now())
        });`

how  i can set default date because code i posted not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
var today = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
$(function() {               
    $("#birthdate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: today
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It should be d.getDate() and not d.getDay(). getDay() returns the day of the week (0 to 6). getDate() returns the day of the month.